# read a JSON file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "course": "CMPT 102 D1", 
    "instructor": "hamarneh", 
    "students": ["axc5", "yqt6"], 
    "title": "Scientific Cmpt.Prgm"
  }, 
  {
    "course": "CMPT 120 D1", 
    "instructor": "diana", 
    "students": ["axc5", "ji12"], 
    "title": "Intro.Cmpt.Sci/Programming I"
  }]
```

1. And I want to convert the file into a variable, so I can manipulate it.
   For example, var array = JSON file
2. How can I access the student name once converted into an array? Is it array[0][2][0] = "axc5"?
3. I tried getJSON but failed, it output the items as objects instead of strings.

Comment: `array[0].students[0]`

Comment: What's wrong with the items being an object?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can read file using below function,

```
 function readFile(fileLocation,callback){
        $.getJSON(fileLocation)
        .done(function( json ) {
            console.log( "JSON Data: "+JSON.stringify(json));
            callback(json);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
            callback(null);
        });
}
```

Here is the calling part

first arg is file location whether it  is local or URL
second arg is callback function

```
 readFile('demo.json',function(result){
        console.log("result "+result);

 });
```

You will receive callback after parsing has been done.

For more detail about $.getJSON visit jQuery official site.